# Why 電話をかける is Ichidan verb, but when using kanji (掛) 電話が掛かる it becomes Godan verb?

Tags: kanji, godan-verbs, ichidan-verbs

I'm learning vocabulary and kanji for those words as well, and I notice in jisho that verb type changes when using kanji or hiragana. 
And does the same thing happen with 出かける - 出掛ける ?

Comment: かかる and かける are intransitive/transitive pairs. Does this answer your question? [とまる / とめる and such pairs of verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14861/%e3%81%a8%e3%81%be%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%a8%e3%82%81%e3%82%8b-and-such-pairs-of-verbs)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19384/5010 Whether to use kanji is not important.